# Drush error — missing module Console_Table

Tags: drush

I want to know how may I resolve this issue !!! I'm using Centos Machine and drush

```
  $ drush status
    Drush needs to download a library from                               [error]
    http://download.pear.php.net/package/Console_Table-1.1.3.tgz in order
    to function, and the attempt to download this file automatically
    failed because you do not have permission to write to the library
    directory /usr/local/share/drush/lib. To continue you will need to
    manually download the package from
    http://download.pear.php.net/package/Console_Table-1.1.3.tgz, extract
    it, and copy the directory into your /usr/local/share/drush/lib
    directory.
```

I've done what it is said in the request but it still give me the same error :

```
$ sudo wget http://download.pear.php.net/package/Console_Table-1.1.3.tgz
$ sudo tar -xzf Console_Table-1.1.3.tgz 
$ sudo mv Console_Table-1.1.3/Table.php usr/local/share/drush/lib/table.inc
```

Comment: You'll probably find it much easier to get rid of that version of drush and install using a more up to date method (i.e. composer). All the dependencies will be installed automatically that way

Comment: Ok, and how may I remove the actual version with all its dependencies ?

Comment: How did you install it? With yum maybe?

Comment: I dont know, because it is not me who has installed this version .. the person has left the job :(

Comment: pear not installed in the server ... composer it is installed

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, you can just install it globally with composer (instructions should be on drush's github page or linked from it), and make sure the composer global bin path is before /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin in your profile

Comment: Ok I reinstalled drush using these command lines : 

$ sudo wget --quiet -O - http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drush-7.x-5.9.tar.gz | sudo tar -zxf - -C /usr/local/share
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush
$ sudo drush

and the things working good actually :) thanks @Clive

Answer (score 2):

Drush 5 is no longer supported.  Install Drush 8 using the [standard installation instructions](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/).